# UITableView - cellForRowAtIndexPath Is Not Being Called

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I know the title is illustrating enough, and I KNOW that this question has been ask a couple of times, but in this case I couldn't manage to make it work.

I already have worked with UITableViews and they all have been working fine, but this time, I even checked my code with other working copies, but it is not working.

So, here's the story :

I have a table view in one of my view controller's in storyboard with a custom class named `ContactViewController`, and it is connected to code using an outlet named `favContactsTable`

Here are related parts from its .h and .m :

**ContactViewController.h**

```
@interface ContactViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource>

// Other Stuff
   .
   .

@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *favContactsTable;

   .
   .
// Other Stuff

@end
```

And here is implemented functions of `UITableViewDataSource` protocol :

**ContactViewController.m**

```
// Rest of the code
.
.
.
.
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 5;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tv cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"TEST OUTPUT");

    //Test
    int a = 1; // Breakpoint
    a++;

    cell = [self.favContactsTable dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"FavContactCell"];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"FavContactCell"];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = @"FAV";
    .
    .
    .
}
```

I have another button in my view controller that reloads data for this table, but when I press it none of the breakpoints is triggered and no log is printed, none of the functions are being called. Here's the code for that button :

```
- (IBAction)refreshTables:(id)sender
{
    [self.favContactsTable reloadData];
}
```

I checked almost every part with my other projects that has a dynamic table view like this, and I can't figure out what's wrong.

Please do not mention other similar questions as duplicates, because I already have read them all ( or at least, most of them ) and I'm sure I'm not returning 0 rows for each section, and I'm sure `favContactsTable` is not `nil` when I send `reloadData` message to it and ... etc !

Any idea that may help is really appreciated.

Comment: are you using custom Cell??

Comment: No , I'm not using a custom cell.

Comment: sounds like somebody forgot to set a "`dataSource`"!

Comment: add this protocols : <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>

Comment: you were set the datasource and delegate method

Comment: Damn it. I forgot data source. Thank you guys. And sorry for miscoding and novice questions !

Comment: why not accepted my answer dude @Unkn0wn.Bit

Comment: Actually it was because my problem was solved before your answer get posted. So I didn't check the topic. But it's no big deal, I accepted it now ;)

Comment: thanks dude. +1 for you @Unkn0wn.Bit

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
@interface myViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource> {


}
```

set delegate

[image]

drag to your viewcontroller icon

[image]

check your cell identifier as same in your code also

[image]

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"SimpleTableCell"];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle
                                      reuseIdentifier:@"SimpleTableCell"];

    }
return cell;

}
```

Answer (score 3):

try this code :

```
    @interface ContactViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate >
.
.
.
```

and then in `viewDidLoad` add delegate to your tableview property example :

```
self.favContactsTable.delegate = self;
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not confirmed these protocols :`UITableViewDataSource`, `UITableViewDelegate`.Add this to your file.

and after that:

```
favContactsTable.delegate=self;

favContactsTable.datasource=self;
```

and attach directly from your `Xib` file.