# ReloadData does not refresh list

Tags: swift, uitableview, reloaddata

I'm having an issue while using reload data to refresh my UITableView.

As a quick description:
This class received an NSNotification contain the object with data that need to added to the list and device must vibrate once that indicate that the data is received. The device itself vibrate but the list does not updated, so no new data is added to the list.

Code when notification is received:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                let object = notification.object as! Attendee
                self.handshakesArray.append(object)
                self.tableViewMain.reloadData()
                AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(UInt32(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate)) 
            })
```

I don't know if this is an iOS issue or my implementation is wrong.

**Edit:**

```
class Shakes: UITableViewController { 
    private var handshakesArray = [Attendee]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    func executeTask(notification:NSNotification) { 
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            let object = notification.object as! Attendee
            self.handshakesArray.append(object)
            self.tableViewMain.reloadData()
            AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(UInt32(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate)) 
        })
    }
    // ........
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think you haven't initialized `self.handshakesArray`. Please initialise it by

```
var self.handshakesArray = [objectType]()
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are setting **datasource** and **delegate** for *self.tableViewMain* in you **viewDidLoad** func or from the storyboard .

`self.tableViewMain.delegate = self
self.tableViewMain.dataSource = self`

Comment: thanks for suggestion @fahad Khan but still de same result the phone vibrate but no update

Comment: did you debug the code and check if the array count is updating and also check if the tableview delegate functions are called or not.

Comment: Yes the array count update but the 'cellForRowAtIndexPath' function does not get called

Comment: Then please check if the tableview outlets are all connected properly. follow this post this will probably solve your problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21794262/uitableview-cellforrowatindexpath-is-not-being-called.